# is there a way to make the for loop run a command like this?

Tags: r, for-loop

i have some datasets named f1998-f2005 and i wanna use looping to run the following commands because it is a hassle to type line after lines of commands, i tried running the following codes to make it more automated:

```
for (i in 1998:2005) {
  model.poissqmle.f1.199(i) <- glm(formula1, data=f199(i), family=quasipoisson()
                                                       
  print (summary(model.poissqmle.f1.199(i)))
}
```

but r returned me the following message:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in:
"                                                       + print (summary(model.poissqmle.f1.199(i)))
}"
```

Thanks for your help, my foundations in R is really weak but i have to use it for one of my research now hence i would really appreciate a kind soul to help me out. Thanks!

Comment: This `f199(i)` won't run, you need either a good naming scheme for you data on you can put all those datasets into a list and loop within said said or even better map on it

Comment: You also are missing a `)` at the end of the line ending with `quasipoisson()`

Comment: So for getting the df's, you can use `get(paste0('f',i))` where `i` would need to loop from 1998 to 2005. As for the model objects I would just put them in a (named) list where the names could be also `paste0('f',i)`.

Comment: We need more information. Are your datasets R data frames or do you have to read them from files? Vectors, data frames, and lists in R use square brackets for indexing not parentheses. `model.poissqmle.f1.199(i)` will be interpreted by R as a request to run the function `model.poissqmle.f1.199` using the argument i. Next, what is `formula1`. Likewise with `data=f199(i)` you are telling R to run function `f199` with the argument i. You probably want to 1) read all of your files into R; 2) run the regression on them and store the results; 3) print the results.

Comment: hi all, thanks for your help. formula 1 is just a simple regression, f1998 - f2005 are data frames. actually dcarlson's last sentence is exactly what i want to do. Is it possible to use looping to do so?